# datatable.js grid with custom html

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using dataTables.js for converting normal html table into grid.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable();
        $(".dataTables_filter input").css({ "background": "blue" });
    });
```

The jQuery dataTables plugin generates its own pagination and search box inputs around custom table. We can style these auto generated elements like i tried changing style of search input.

But my problem is that i am using a bootstrap template. my template suggest that to style a drop down or a text boxes should be wrapped by some other divs to make it responsive and all.

Is it possible to use my own html for drop down and search boxes and pagination and DataTable use it for all of its magic?

Comment: You actually allready have the possibility to integrate dataTables compltely with bootstrap - see this -> http://jsfiddle.net/9og3u3e5/ if this is what you are looking for, I'll produce an answer.

Comment: ).dataTable(); call is some how corrupting my template css styles.